# Rendering error #Youtube Player

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to embed youtube videos in my android app.

But am not able to render the xml and hence the app is crashing.

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".WelcomePage">
    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**WelcomePage.java**

`public class WelcomePage extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {`

**Error stack while rendering the xml document.**

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:437)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:154)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:93)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:190)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:223)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:511)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:499)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:499)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:611)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:608)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:363)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:608)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:630)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

I will really appreciate if someone can help me out here. I don't know what's wrong here.

**Edit: Adding the activity code.**

`public class WelcomePage extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener 
{

```
private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcomepage);

    youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo("fhWaJi1Hsfo"); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
    }
}
@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
        errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
    } else {
        String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), errorReason.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
        // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
        getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
    }
}

protected Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return youTubeView;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}`

Thanks.

Comment: are you initializing the YouTubePlayerView in you Activity onCreate method ? Can you post your activity code ?

Comment: Yes,am initializing the YouTubePlayerView in onCreate method. Am adding the activity code in question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your strings.xml file, that's why I was getting a red R.id error anyway...